# How do I connect my android app with google app engine?

Tags: java, android, http, servlets, post

I am having trouble inputing data into my google app engine data store.

I have a button on my app (virtual android), and when pushed this string "Value my user entered" should be inputed into my datastore in google app engine under "myContent". But nothing happens. The string does not get input into my datastore.

I have mapped by servlet to /post
Here is my code:

Android App:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        buttonListener();
    }

    public void buttonListener() {
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {
                    DefaultHttpClient hc=new DefaultHttpClient();
                    ResponseHandler <String> res=new BasicResponseHandler();
                    HttpPost postMethod=new HttpPost("http://somegooglesite.appspot.com/post");
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("value1", "Value my user entered")); 

                    postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));  
                    HttpResponse response = hc.execute(postMethod);
                    //String response=hc.execute(postMethod,res);
                }
                catch(Exception e){

                }

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Servlet:

```
package guestbook;



public class PostFormServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {

        String value1 = req.getParameter("value1");
        Entity postt = new Entity("Posts");
        postt.setProperty("myContent", value1);
        DatastoreService datastoree = DatastoreServiceFactory
                .getDatastoreService();
        datastoree.put(postt);
    }

}
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

I did add permission to my android app to use the internet if that narrows anything down.

Thank you!

Comment: _But nothing happens_ Something must surely happen...Put some log statements in between method calls. `NetworkOnMainThreadException` comes to mind.

Comment: I just tried this. Added few logs in every statement in my buttonListener. Everything seems to work. With no errors

Comment: What does `HttpResponse response` contain? Make your servlet do something to the response, like print `hello` to the outputstream.

Comment: Is the use of response required? I am just trying to input to datastore with request.

Comment: It is not required, but it'll help us debug. At least check the response code.

Comment: How would I check? I just added this to my servlet

out.println("Test");
out.println(value1);

Comment: Look at the api for [HttpResponse](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html#getStatusLine()). There's a method in there for getting the status line and then the code. Now that you've written something to the response, you can even get the body of the response to see if it outprint "Test" and whatever is in `value1`